# How to write Arabic poetry on LyX?

Tags: xetex, lyx, arabic

In Arabi package documentation, it possible to write Arabic poetry on LaTeX using that package. But, I want to write Arabic poetry using LyX, that uses LaTeX as its backend and XeTeX for formatting external fonts for Arabic and other languages.

On Arabi package documentation, someone can write Arabic poetry using this macro, after previously having to include `poetry` package:

```
\Halfverses{ ﻓﺎﻟﺨﻄﺐ أﻓﻈﻊ ﻣﻦ ﺳﺮاء ﺗﺄﻣﻠﻬـﺎ } { واﻷﻣﺮ أﻳﺴﺮ ﻣﻦ أن ﺗﻀﻤﺮ اﻟﺮﻋﺒـﺎ }
```

Also:

```
\Connverses{ ﻓﺎﻟﻠﺐ إن ﺻﺢ أﻋﻄﻰ اﻟﻨﻔﺲ ﻓﺘﺮﺗﻬﺎ }{٭} { ﺣﺘﻰ ﺗﻤﻮت ، وﺳﻤﻰ ﺟﺪﻫﺎ ﻟﻌﺒﺎ }
```

How I can accomplish this on LyX?. For addition, I added this to my LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{poetry}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh}

\date{}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\arabic* , leftmargin=*}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```